# Create a Google like instant search in an Android app

Tags: android, textbox, search-engine, android-search, instant

I am working on an Android app in which i want to add an instant search feature.

Basically I want to show places name when the user writes its initials in a `TextBox`.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Thankyou so much for your help :). Basically I wanted to implement Google directions in my app for which i want the user to enter source and destination to get the direction. What i want is that when user enter the one or two initials of the place it shows all the places starting from these initials. Do i need to manually add all the places name or is there any built in function or Google API for it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you must include all cities in a list or download them from any city/country listing site :) ..

Answer (score 0):

## Building the interface

You can use [InstantSearch Android](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch-android/), which is an open-source library to help you easily build instant search experiences on Android using [Algolia](https://algolia.com).

It is [available on GitHub](https://github.com/algolia/instantsearch-android) and lets you build quickly an instant search UI. See for example the [InstantSearch Media application](https://github.com/algolia/instantsearch-android-examples/tree/master/media):

[image: Example media application]

You can start with the [Getting Started Guide](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch-android/getting-started.html) which will take you through the main steps to use the library.

[The example applications](https://github.com/algolia/instantsearch-android-examples) can give you an idea of what you can build with InstantSearch Android.

## Using the data

If you have the places data you want to search in, you can [simply index it in Algolia](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/indexing/synchronization/) and it will be searchable in your app.

If you don't have the data somewhere, have a look at [Algolia Places](http://algolia.com/places) which provides a **free access** to a worldwide places database.

*Disclaimer: I am the author of InstantSearch Android.*